# ITextPDF - Rectangle color is overlapping/hidding chunk's text

Tags: java, pdf, colors, itext

What I need is to draw multiple rounded rectangles in a particular coordinates set of the PDF. I used [this example](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/events-for-basic-building-blocks-itext-5/) (IMDB one) to get the `Chunks`' coordinates dinamically (using `PdfPageEvent` and its `onGenericTag()` method). It is getting the `Chunks`' coordinates perfectly and placing the rectangles where they have to be. The problem comes when I set them color, colors totally hide the text. I know the texts are there because I'm actually able to copy them. If I don't apply colors, texts are visible.

This is how they actually look if I don't apply colors:

[image]

And this is how they look if I apply colors (this is how they should look, but including text): 
[image]

Ignore differences in terms of rectangles sizes, I just overrided original texts by examples, but originals are shown perfectly.
Why the text gets hidden? I know this can be done because of the example, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.
I am using 5.5.13 version.

This is how I create and add the chunks to the paragraph:

```
List<Chunk> chunksList = new ArrayList<>(); //rects
            Chunk rdChunk;
            for(Person rd: persons) {
                rdChunk = new Chunk(rd.getName(), textFont);
                rdChunk.setGenericTag(rd.getName());
                chunksList .add(rdChunk);
            }
            document.add(createParagraph("as: ", chunksList , basicLeftIndentation));

private Paragraph createParagraph(String field, List<Chunk> chunks, long leftIndentation) {

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

    paragraph.add(new Chunk(field, labelFont));
    for(Chunk chunk: chunks) {
        paragraph.add(new Chunk("  "));
        paragraph.add(chunk);
    }
    paragraph.setIndentationLeft(leftIndentation);

    return paragraph;
}
```

And this is how I use the PdfPageEvent interface:

```
@Override
public void onGenericTag(PdfWriter writer, Document document, Rectangle rect, String text) {
    int[] colors;
    switch(text) {

    case "XX":
        colors = new int[]{142, 166, 207};
        break;
    case "XY":
        colors = new int[]{207, 188, 142};
        break;

    drawRectangle(writer.getDirectContent(), rect, colors);
}

public void drawRectangle(PdfContentByte content, Rectangle rect, int[] colors) {

    content.saveState();
    content.roundRectangle(rect.getLeft() -2,
                      rect.getBottom() - 3,
                      rect.getWidth() + 4,
                      rect.getHeight() + 4, 7f);
    content.setRGBColorFill(colors[0], colors[1], colors[2]);
    content.fill();
    content.restoreState();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was calling

```
writer.getDirectContent();
```

instead of

```
writer.getDirectContentUnder();
```